# Parâmetros da função CvRTrees::train() - OpenCV / C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Olá!

Preciso utilizar a função `CvRTrees::train()` do OpenCV, mas não entendo muito bem os parâmetros utilizados. Para ajudar, o site não possui documentação sobre os parâmetros desta função.

A especificação da função é:

```
bool CvDTree::train(const Mat& trainData, 
                    int tflag, 
                    const Mat& responses, 
                    const Mat& varIdx=Mat(), 
                    const Mat& sampleIdx=Mat(), 
                    const Mat& varType=Mat(), 
                    const Mat& missingDataMask=Mat(), 
                    CvDTreeParams params=CvDTreeParams() )
```

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando uma versão desatualizada do opencv!

Baixe a última versão [aqui](http://opencv.org/downloads.html), pois nela toda a parte referente a [Random Trees](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dd6/ml_intro.html#ml_intro_rtrees&gsc.tab=0) foi reformulada para facilitar a utilização, conforme pode ser observado na [Documentação Oficial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/d65/classcv_1_1ml_1_1RTrees.html#gsc.tab=0).

Além disso, nessa nova versão você também vai encontrar [exemplos de implementação](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tree_engine.cpp)!

Se ainda restarem dúvidas, sinta-se a vontade para questionar!